# Simple app is crashing I am just traying to change the visibility of some views

Tags: java, android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button b1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
TextView tvl=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);

 

    public void clickGo(View view)
        {
            b1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            tvl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
   

     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        
            }
        }
```

I am trying to disappear the button and allow text to be visible this is code I am not able to find why it is crashing please help.

Comment: what's the error you get?

Comment: Please include the stacktrace of the crash.

Comment: that means either b1 or tv1 is not found in activity_main

Comment: @AIMINPAN no, it's because you can't do find view by ID before setContentView

Answer (score 0):

The reason your app is crashing it's because your'e trying to `setVisibility` something that is null becasue the way you initialized your views is not correct,
and you need you do it like this.
Without a constructor.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button b1;
TextView tvl;

       @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         b1 = findViewById(R.id.button);
         tvl = findViewById(R.id.text);
         b1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
         tvl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**lets try this bro**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        
    
             @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                  Button b1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
                 TextView tvl=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                b1.setOnClickListener(v -> {

                b1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                tvl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                   
               }           
          }
       }
```